# find not working while I am trying to create a vector containing unique elements in c++

Tags: c++, vector, find

Find not working while I am trying to create a vector containing unique elements.

The string is first tokenized and then it need to be reversed. but elememts in reversed string must be unique.

```
   #include <cstring>
    #include <vector>
    #include <algorithm>
    #include <iostream>
    using namespace std;
    int main()
    {
        vector<char *> myvec;
        string input;
        getline(cin,input);
        char *token = std::strtok((char *)input.c_str()," ");
        while (token != NULL)
        {
            if(find(myvec.begin(), myvec.end(), token)  != myvec.end())
              cout<< "\n Skipping duplicate";
            else
              myvec.push_back(token);
            token = std::strtok(NULL, " ");
        }
        cout<<endl;
        while (!myvec.empty())
        {
          cout<<myvec.back();
          myvec.pop_back();
          cout<<" ";
        }
    cout<<endl;
    }

    Input: A bird came down the walk down END
    Output: END down walk the down came bird A

   Down should be removed from output as it is duplicate word.
```

Comment: Undefined behavior because the return value of `.c_str()` is `const`

Comment: You are skipping duplicate **pointers** not duplicate text.

Comment: @Alain: There is not issue in tokenising. But issue is with find.

Comment: @Galik: how to hand find in this case?

Comment: I agree with @Galik . Try this: use a `vector<char>` without pointers and in the if statement use `*token`

Comment: You're searching for pointers. The two 'down's are in different places, so they can't compare equal. Use `std::string` instead of the ancient C library.

Comment: @user3069523 `strtok` modifies the input string. Undefined behavior is never "not an issue" IMO.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you are storing pointers to char, not strings:

```
vector<char *> myvec;
```

instead of

```
vector<string> myvec;
```

So, when you write your input:

```
A bird came down the walk down END
            ^             ^
```

these two "down" are different words, and they are stored in differents posititions of memory, and because of that their address are different.

A similar code that works, but using strings, is the following:

```
string input;
getline(cin, input);

stringstream str;
str << input;

vector<string> v;
while (str >> input){
    if (find(v.begin(), v.end(), input) == v.end())
        v.push_back(input);
}

cout <<  '\n';

for(auto p = v.rbegin(); p != v.rend(); ++p)
    cout << *p << ' ';

cout << '\n';
```

Answer (score 0):

Since `vector<char*>` is a vector of pointers and `token` is a pointer as well, you are comparing pointers. The two different pointers point to different values, then they are not equal.

Insert this in your code, and you will see the difference:

```
std::cout << "Memory address: " << token << " value: " << *token << std::endl;
```

You want to compare the values, not the pointers. As said in the comments, you can try to use `vector<char>` and then use `*token`, or use `vector<string>` directly (so you can also avoid `input.c_str()`).

PS: if you want to still use `char*` in the vector, you can implement a simple function like this:

```
bool check_character(vector<char*> vec, char* token)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < vec.size(); i++ )
    {
        if (*(vec.at(i)) == *token)
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

(ps code not tested)

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of issues with your code. First you are casting away `const` when you do `(char*) input.c_str()` which can cause undefined behavior.

Otherwise your `std::find()` is looking for duplicate *pointers* it is not comparing the content of the strings they point to. For that you need a string comparison function like `std::strcmp`. The [std::find_if](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find) function allows you do supply your own complex comparison function (in the code below I used a lambda).

```
int main()
{
    std::vector<char*> myvec;

    std::string input = "A bird came down the walk down END";

    // removed for exposition
    // std::getline(cin, input);

    // don't cast away const, use the address of the first element
    // THIS ONLY WORKS AFTER C++11
    // (because no guarantee of null terminator before that)
    char* token = std::strtok(&input[0], " ");

    while(token != NULL)
    {
        // use find_if() to compare zero-terminated strings using std::strcmp
        if(find_if(myvec.begin(), myvec.end(),
            [token](char* t){ return std::strcmp(t, token) == 0; }) != myvec.end())

            std::cout << "\n Skipping duplicate";
        else
            myvec.push_back(token);

        token = std::strtok(NULL, " ");
    }

    std::cout << '\n';

    while(!myvec.empty())
    {
        std::cout << myvec.back();
        myvec.pop_back();
        std::cout << " ";
    }

    std::cout << '\n';
}
```